# sorting alphanumeric in mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

```
040, 044P, 041BL, 041W, 041PB
```

^^ This is the order it is coming out in by using Order By clause.

I think this is how it should appear instead:

```
040, 041BL, 041PB, 041W, 044P
```

I know similar questions must have been asked before, but I still can't figure out anything!

Edit: After X.L.Ant's comment, I realized my mistake. Therefore, simple order by clause is working for the test case given above. However, the case is still complicated if the number of digits is not always going to be 3 as GolezTrol mentioned. What should one do in that case?

Comment: [This fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/37927/1) outputs in the right order...

Comment: If the string always starts with exactly 3 digits, then no special action needs to be taken. You can just sort it. The tricky part is when the length of the number varies and you still want to sort it numerologically by the leading number and alphabetically by the part after the number.

Comment: @GolezTrol The string does not always start with 3 digits. The string could have any number of digits and letters

Comment: @user1831003 This shows the importance of using real data in your question. For the given data, a normal order by would work fine, and now we are (were) confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
SELECT string,
       @num := CONVERT(string, signed)                            AS num_part,
       Substring(Trim(LEADING '0' FROM string), Length(@num) + 1) AS rest_of_string
FROM   table1
ORDER  BY num_part,
          rest_of_string
```

This way, the numbers will still be ordered by their numerical value (the leading 0s not being taken into account).

See [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d7281/2).

Comment: aren't you the champ!

Comment: Why did this answer get downvoted? I used this answer... is there something wrong with this?

Comment: Sure. this answer eliminates all the possible use of indexes.

Comment: @YourCommonSense Do you have any proposition on how to enforce correct order and make a use of indices?

Comment: @YourCommonSense I agree, but unless there is some way to avoid any kind of string manipulation, I don't see how to preserve the use of indexes.

Comment: The answer is right for the database as it is, so I upvoted it. A better solution might be to change the database and store the numeric prefix in a separate integer field. By splitting the data, you can maintain indexes while sorting the way you want.

Answer (score -1):

try `LPAD()` function - but remeber that `LPAD` trims digits.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d7281/3/0

Comment: Can you elaborate your answer ?

Comment: '044P' still comes before '041BL'.

Comment: Sorry, didn't take under consideration that there is various no. of chars in back. I was wrong because i had once similar problem but there was wrong sorting order like: 1A, 10B, 11A, 2A, 213D, 3A... instead of:1A, 2A, 3A, 10B, 11A, 213D - it was PHP issue resolved by MySQL site by `LPAD`